# Need Help in Creating a Cookie

Tags: javascript, cookies

I have a button named *yes* and another named *no*.

```
<input type="button" name="yes" onclick="button()">
<input type="button" name="no">
```

I want to create a cookie when *yes* is clicked that would store the info "YES" and needs to expire after 7 days. How do i do that? The only information that the cookie needs to store is "YES".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [document.cookie](http://www.elated.com/articles/javascript-and-cookies/):

```
var expDate = new Date();
expDate.setDate(expDate.getDate() + 7);
document.cookie = 'your_cookie_name=YES;expires=' + expDate.toUTCString();
```

Or if you are using jquery you may take a look at the [Cookie plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/Cookie). Here's an [example](http://www.electrictoolbox.com/jquery-cookies/).

Comment: Read document.cookie like a string. It will have values like "userName=Bill;favoriteColor=Red;timezone=GMT". Username/Favorite Color and Timezone are al different cookies, so parse the string how'd you like to get the one you want.

Comment: @ryan, take a look at the *Retrieving cookies* paragraph in the [article](http://www.elated.com/articles/javascript-and-cookies/) I've linked to.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what i use

```
var cookie = {
    "create": function(name, value, days) {
        if (typeof days !== 'number' || typeof name !== 'string' || typeof value !== 'string') {
            return false;
        }
        var date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime() + (days*86400000));
        document.cookie = name + '=' + value + '; expires=' + date.toGMTString() + '; path=/';
    },
    "read": function(name) {
        var cookie = document.cookie,
            i, val = false;
        cookie = cookie.split(';');
        for (i = 0; i < cookie.length; i++) {
            if (cookie[i].indexOf(name) !== -1) {
                while (cookie[i].indexOf(name) > 0 && cookie[i].length > name.length) {
                    cookie[i] = cookie[i].substr(1);
                }
                val = cookie[i].substr(name.length + 1);
            }
        }
        return val;
    },
    "erase": function(name) {
        this.create(name, '', -1);
    }
};
```

You can then use:

```
cookie.create("userName", "Bill", 7); // store userName "Bill" for 7 days.

cookie.read("userName"); // "Bill"

cookie.erase("userName");
```

Here's a fiddle to see how it works. http://jsfiddle.net/robert/4vLT6/