# Checking for cookie on Page Load

Tags: javascript, dom, cookies

I want the browser to start by checking if a cookie with the name "yes" exists.

If so, I want to display a message.

If not, I want to display this:

```
<input type="button" id='approve' value="approve" onclick="a()"/>
<input type="button" id='reject' value="reject" onclick="r()"/>
```

How do I achieve this? I want it to be client side.

Comment: Why did you delete the code you already had? And I suppose you mean with "display" (2nd time) "insert into the DOM"?

Comment: I thought i'd make it easier to understand..should i put it back?

Comment: I'm having Déjà vu. I don't suppose this is anything to do with http://stackoverflow.com/q/4173586/393783 ?

Comment: @dan-waterworth Oh no...this is different.

Comment: Yes, please, put it back; we like to see what you've tried so far yourself. @dan: yes, I suppose so, but the other way around.

Comment: Hey, thanks for all your help...i figured it out. Yipee.

Answer (score 2):

The quick and dirty way would be to use document.write() inline. Lets say there is a predefined cookie getter function:

```
// taken from http://www.elated.com/articles/javascript-and-cookies/
function get_cookie ( cookie_name ){
  var results = document.cookie.match ( '(^|;) ?' + cookie_name + '=([^;]*)(;|$)' );
  if ( results )
    return ( unescape ( results[2] ) );
  else
    return null;
}
```

and then in your html somewhere:

```
<div id="container">
    <script>
    if (get_cookie("cookiename") == null){
        document.write("[cookie exists message]")
    } else {
        document.write('<input type="button" id='approve' value="approve" onclick="a()"/><input type="button" id='reject' value="reject" onclick="r()"/>')
    }
    </script>
</div>
```

If you want to render after the page has been loaded:

```
function showit(){
    var myhtml;
    if (get_cookie("cookiename") == null){
        myhtml = "some message";
    } else {
        myhtml = '<input type="button" id='approve' value="approve" onclick="a()"/><input type="button" id='reject' value="reject" onclick="r()"/>'
    }
    document.getElementById("container").innerHTML = myhtml;
}
```